# Regexp MySql- Only strings containing two words

Tags: mysql, regex

I have table with rows of strings.
I'd like to search for those strings that consists of only
two words.

I tried few ways with [[:space:]] etc but mysql was returning
three, four word strings also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
select * from yourTable WHERE field REGEXP('^[[:alnum:]]+[[:blank:]]+[[:alnum:]]+$');
```

more details in link :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 1):

`^\w+\s\w+$` should do well.

Note; what I experience more often in the last days is that close to nobody uses the `^$`-operators.

They are absolutely needed if you want to tell if a string starts or ends with something or want to match the string exactly, word for word, as you. "Normal" strings, like you used (I assume you used something like `\w[:space]\w` match **in the string**, what means that they also match if the condition is true **anywhere within the string**!

Keep that in mind and Regex will serve you well :)

Comment: That was happening. As to "^\w\s\w+$"  it didn't show results. I got mysql 5.0,  maybe thats the reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
 REGEXP ('^[a-z0-9]*[[:space:]][a-z0-9]*$')
```